# Galleria + Colorbox working in IE, not in others

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, galleria

I thought I had this worked out, but unfortunately it does not work in FF or Chrome.  I have a list of images that I would like displayed as a slideshow with carousel on my page.  When the user clicks on the larger image I would like it to open a full size image in a lightbox.  Here is the code that works in IE:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/galleria.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/galleria.classic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel=test]').colorbox();

    $('#exteriorSlideShow_gallery').galleria({
        max_scale_ratio: 1,
        image_crop: false,
        height: 210,
        transition: 'fade',
        extend: function() {
            this.bind(Galleria.LOADFINISH, function(e) {
                $(e.imageTarget).click(this.proxy(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('a[rel=test]').eq(this.active).click();
                }));
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

In the above, "this.active" represents the index of the image in which the carousel is currently on.  Since it is in the same order the links below are displayed in, it corresponds to the correct link I would like to have clicked.

```
<div id="exteriorSlideShow_gallery">
    <a href="/Images/ORIG1.gif" rel="test"><img src='/Images/THUMB1.gif' /></a>
    <a href="/Images/ORIG2.gif" rel="test"><img src='/Images/THUMB2.gif' /></a>
    <a href="/Images/ORIG3.gif" rel="test"><img src='/Images/THUMB3.gif' /></a>
</div>
```

Anyone know why this wouldn't work in anything but IE?

*EDIT*
For the time being I have put in a work around.  If the browser is IE I call the code as above else I use $.colorbox({ 'href': urloflargeimage }).  This doesn't allow grouping of the images for anything but IE, but at least I have a lightbox up.

Comment: Use $(this) instead of this.Can we acces the page online, did you catch any errors with firebug?

Comment: In that context $(this).active causes it to stop working in IE even.  When I put a breakpoint on the click event in firebug it does get hit, but when continuing nothing happens.  I don't have it accessible at the moment, I'll try to get something up for you.  Thanks

Comment: Something works in IE and not others?  That's a first.

Comment: How does this "active" attribute get set up?  In fact, what is the "this" reference pointing at; a DOM element or an object controlled by this plugin?  The documentation for that thing is a real pain to read.

Comment: It's a bit confusing to me also, I'm a bit lost with the galleria code, but it is referencing the carousel of thumbnails.  It's an object controlled by Galleria.  So this.active returns the index of the thumbnail that is actively showing on the midsized image stage.


@Peter That's why I started by looking for misformed tags, etc. :) I figured if it was working in IE and not others it must be a broken page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galleria strips most of your container content after grabbing necessary data, but it leaves it hidden in IE because of a loading bug. That is why your hack works in IE but not elsewhere.

I'm not sure how colorbox works, but it looks like it cannot take a normal array of URLs and assign it as a group of images and then call each box manually onclick. But you might be able to do something like this (hack):

```
var box = $('a[rel=test]').clone().colorbox(); // save the colorbox array

$('#exteriorSlideShow_gallery').galleria({
    extend: function() {
        this.bind(Galleria.LOADFINISH, function(e) {
            var index = this.active;
            $(e.imageTarget).bind('click', { active: this.active }, function(ev) {
                box.eq(ev.data.active).click();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That explains the behavior, thank you David. Your solution works for calling up a single image, but unfortunately loses the grouping functionality I seek. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: If it's any help, galleria will include a lightbox function in the next release so you dont have to use external plugins for that.

Comment: That's great news, I see you commit to the project, thank you for the tool.  I will wander over to github and see if I can help with testing or anything for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this. You have to put the links outside the galleria container, separate from the images, then click them when an image is clicked. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
$('a[rel="lightbox"]').colorbox();
var targ;

$("#gallery").galleria({
    autoplay: 6000,
    transitionSpeed: 1000,
    transitionInitial: 'fade',
    width: 958,
    height: 443,
    imageCrop: 'width',
    minScaleRatio: 1,
    extend: function() {
        this.bind(Galleria.IMAGE, function(e) {

            $(e.imageTarget).css('cursor','pointer');

            $(e.imageTarget).click(this.proxy(function() {

                targ = $(e.imageTarget).attr('src');

                $('a[href="'+targ+'"]').click();

            }));
        });
    }

});
```

});

and the HTML looks like:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="images/jqIm4.jpg" />
    <img src="images/jqIm5.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="source">
    <a href="images/jqIm4.jpg" rel="lightbox"></a>
    <a href="images/jqIm5.jpg" rel="lightbox"></a>              
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script tag is missing a quote character. Is it like that in your actual source? If so, that could seriously upset Firefox.

Specifically

```
<script type="text/javascript>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Good catch, but it was simply a typo here. Source has both. Thank you